# C# MVC 5 Multiple routes not working server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a project that I tried to make the mapping "short" for the Urls to look beautiful.

In my environment it is working, however when publishing to the server it gives the error below.

Url my site: www.papodealemao.com.br

#### My Routes

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Pagina",
        url: "pagina/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Principal", action = "Index", id = "1" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Secao",
        url: "Secao/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "Secao" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Categoria",
        url: "Categoria/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "Categoria" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "PorData",
        url: "PorData/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "PorData" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Artigo",
        url: "artigo/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "Artigo" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Tag",
        url: "Tag/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "Tag" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Principal", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

#### Error

```
Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Blog'. This can happen if the route that services this request ('artigo/{id}') does not specify namespaces to search for a controller that matches the request. If this is the case, register this route by calling an overload of the 'MapRoute' method that takes a 'namespaces' parameter.

The request for 'Blog' has found the following matching controllers:
PapoDeAlemao.Controllers.BlogController
blog.Controllers.BlogController

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Blog'. This can happen if the route that services this request ('artigo/{id}') does not specify namespaces to search for a controller that matches the request. If this is the case, register this route by calling an overload of the 'MapRoute' method that takes a 'namespaces' parameter.

The request for 'Blog' has found the following matching controllers:
PapoDeAlemao.Controllers.BlogController
blog.Controllers.BlogController
```

#### Visual Studio

[image]

Comment: You have multiple classes called `BlogController` and route table does not know which one you want to route to. Find out where the controller in `PapoDeAlemao.Controllers` namespace is and remove it. Could be that it is stray code you meant to delete.

Comment: How do I resolve this? Why in my local environment does it work? @Nkosi

Comment: Post your controller actions method sigs.

Comment: @MarlonTiedt Could be a dll left on the server that is still referencing old code

Comment: @Nkosi I deleted all files the project in server and upload new version and routes working. Something stuck with the new version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add namespaces to the route indicating which `BlogController` your want, i.e.:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Secao",
    url: "Secao/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "Secao" },
    namespaces: new[] { "PapoDeAlemao.Controllers" }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason of the error is that you have to classes named "`BlogController`" once inside "Controllers" folder and one inside "PapoDeAlemao/Controllers" folder. Please unify then in one class and the error will be gone.

OR

You may namespace routing

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Secao",
    url: "Secao/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "Secao" },
    namespaces: new[] { "PapoDeAlemao.Controllers" }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that you have multiple classes called `BlogController` and route table does not know which one you want to route to. Could be that it is stray code you meant to delete. Could also be an old dll left on the server that is still referencing old code.

Try clearing previous files and publish afresh.